# Mono is crashing on MAC OS X with Keepass 2.23

Tags: macos, keepass, mono-framework

Mono is  crashing on MAC OS X (10.8.4) with Keepass 2.23 while accessing
password database.

Using keepasshttp with firefox.

Any workaround for this ?

===========================================================
Process:         mono-sgen [7586]
Path:            /usr/bin/mono
Identifier:      mono-sgen
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [7194]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-08-15 13:34:28.515 +0530
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.4 (12E55)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          1736954 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           415
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5
Anonymous UUID:                      718933CD-E40F-E149-90FB-657A80079D13

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** error for object 0x7b177b20: double free

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x966f8a6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98dc6b2f pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98dfd4ec abort + 168
3   mono                              0x0010a620 mono_handle_native_sigsegv +
592
4   mono                              0x0015fcbd sigabrt_signal_handler + 109
5   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98db18cb _sigtramp + 43
6   ???                               0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
7   mono                              0x0015fc50 sigusr1_signal_handler + 272
8   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98dfd4ec abort + 168
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98de7227 szone_error + 443
10  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98de84ec free_tiny_botch + 101
11  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x98ddfd30 free + 217

Answer (score -1):

Try KyPass Companion.

It includes an internal keepasshttp server: http://www.kyuran.be/

Comment: "KyPass Companion" is a paid product fork of the free KeePass application. It would be much more helpful to fix the problem with the application cited by the OP.